# Cloud Function Affect Read/Write Quotas

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for clarification on how the actions triggered by cloud functions affect the cost of hosting an app with Firebase.

My situation:

- I have a cloud function that is triggered when a post is made...that cloud function writes that post to all of the appropriate uid's on the /feed node mentioned below.
- I am using Firestore to host a feed/follow system. It is setup with each user having their own feed at the following path

  */feed/{uid}/posts*

My question is, if a user has 1,000,000 followers...does that translate to 1,000,000 writes in the eyes of Firestore?

Does that mean that single post will cost $1.80 to distribute? Based on the cost of $0.18/100k writes.

I am just trying to see how this will scale with thousands of users posting dozens of posts...those distribution costs seem very expensive at scale for this situation.

**EDIT**

It looks like it does cost for every read/write in a cloud function base on the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=49&v=6NegFl9p_sE&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Watched this video...https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=49&v=6NegFl9p_sE&feature=emb_logo...relates well to this question

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is going on here. Could you edit the question to show the code that's being executed? We need to be able to see the function definition as well as the code that's writing the documents. Nothing should be left to the imagination.

Comment: Every read/write is billed, even from Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are writing to Firestore, but bottom line is that yes, you get billed for each read/write operation performed to Firestore as mentioned over at their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example#operations).

Additionally, you get billed per Cloud Function invocation as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing), so you would need to keep this in mind if you want to keep your expenses low.

Hope you find this useful.